# Change whatsapp emojis on Android

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to replace the Whatsapp emojis with my own.
Is it possible with just an APK file?
What should I look into?
Is root neccessary?
Thanks!

Comment: check this link: http://www.loudtechie.com/how-to-add-or-edit-whatsapp-custom-emoticons/

Comment: You can do it with [KMod](http://repo.xposed.info/module/kmod.xposed) wich requires [the XPosed framework](repo.xposed.info).

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that provide the app with emoji
Search for it in the app directory in /data , try to decompile it and change resources

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Whatsapp stores its emoticons, but basically if it stores them in /data catalog you need to be root to see and edit locations under /data.
If all emoticons are pre-loaded in the apk file you can try to replace them by extracting the resources with apktool, exchange them and put back into apk. 
You will find some articles with a google about replacing resources in an apk file.

In most cases it will mess with apk signature but maybe this solution will help.
 
Good luck